# Css overflow hidden won't work, despite position relative for parent

Tags: css, position, overflow

I would like to hide some part of the child, so everything outside of the parent container isn't visible (so part of my picture should be cropped by the height of the container)

I followed lot of forums answer that told to put the container to relative (mine must be relative so this wasn't a problem)

```css
.img-container {
  margin : auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:250px;
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  border : 5px dotted gray;
}

.img-container object, .img-container img{
  position : absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img1{
  top : 0px;
  left : 0px;
  width:60%;
}

.img2{
  width: 52%;
  left :120px;
  top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <object class='img1' data='https://svgshare.com/i/6Pz.svg'>

  </object>
  <object class='img2' data='https://svgshare.com/i/6Pz.svg'>

  </object>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u0upm3j3/2/

ANSWER :

Well well well... Something that i don't understand : it work now.

What did i do ? Nothing at all, apart of restarting Chrome.

Thanks you D3nj, Cavdi for your answer and Creaforge and Daniel for comment, sorry to make you lose a bit your time. But really, i don't understand how it can work now and not before...

The example in the pos is working good.

Comment: In the jsfiddle you provided the code works to hide the child element within the container height. Please include the HTML mark up for your problem so that it can be replicated. [mcve]

Comment: i don't understand what you mean because my code doesn't work as expected. Everything outside of the parent container shouldn't be visible.

Comment: Can you do without `<object>`? As far as I remember there is no overflow on objects, but I can't find the official specification.

Comment: @Creaforge Been searching for while for this in spec but can't seem to find it. Do you remember where you saw this outside the spec as I would like to read up on it?

Comment: @Creaforge well i tried from this example and object tag overflowing the container was hidden https://www.studytonight.com/code/playground/web?file=css-overflow_hidden

Comment: @Daniel ohh, i've understand that my jsfiddle wasn't upto date ! So i fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img-container {
  margin : auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width:250px;
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  border : 5px dotted gray;
}

.img-container object, .img-container img{
  position : absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img1{
  top : 0px;
  left : 0px;
  width:60%;
}

.img2{
  width: 52%;
  left :120px;
  top:50px;
}
```

Comment: don't understand how it supposed to help

Comment: I added the `overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: `Overflow: hidden;` Does nothing ^^

Comment: Also you need to add a class to the object inside the div.

`code`

Comment: If it fixed your problem please choose this as the answer :-)

Comment: well, from this example, ´overflow:hidden;´ seems to work great : https://www.studytonight.com/code/playground/web?file=css-overflow_hidden

Comment: Does it work with your script? No.
Try my changes and then get back ^^

Comment: i put an answer to explain and close my case, just to say that overflow:hidden is working, as you can see there : https://jsfiddle.net/u0upm3j3/3/

Answer (score 0):

use this as general on your css and remove the overflow from the image style

```
*, html, body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```